# MongoDB: How to get documents according to the number of matched values

Tags: java, mongodb

How to get documents according to the number of matched values in ***MongoDB***?

I have 100 documents that have field 'hobbies'. 
All documents have hobbies with different values like we people have.

e.g

1st document: {"hobbies":"sketching, singing, dancing, reading, woodworking"}

2nd document: {"hobbies":"riding, reading"}

3rd document: {"hobbies":"reading, woodworking"}

etc...

Suppose, I have passed 3 values(reading, singing, woodworking) for the same field 'hobbies', so in return as output I should get the documents first that have matched all 3 values , then the documents that have matched 2 values, then the documents that have matched 1 value.

**How can I do the same with any number of values?**

***What should be the query?***

I'm comfortable with **Java** also, so you can use java also with **MongoDB**.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: is hobbies a field with values delimited by comma or it's a set?

Comment: @Saravana . Yes, values are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do this is using MongoDB's [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

To get what described in your requirement use following:

- **Create text index**: on `hobbies` key as: `db.people.ensureIndex({hobbies:"text"})`
- **Perform serach**: using $search and $text operator using [sort by text search scrore as](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#sort-by-text-search-score):

  `db.people.find({$text:{$search: "reading, singing, woodworking"}},{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )`

This will return you the documents in decreasing order of relevance:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7606a692a0280a17c67ead"),
    "hobbies" : "sketching, singing, dancing, reading, woodworking",
    "score" : 1.7999999999999998
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7606bf92a0280a17c67eaf"),
    "hobbies" : "reading, woodworking",
    "score" : 1.5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7606b392a0280a17c67eae"),
    "hobbies" : "riding, reading",
    "score" : 0.75
}
```